# Android Login using PHP and MySql Database

Tags: android

Hi I am trying to validate a user login but it lets me login even if i put wrong user name and password. Any help please. 
I am student.

```
      private class sendPostData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
     {
         @Override
         protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

             try{

                 String link="http://www.md-miz.byethost24.com/htdocs/check.php";
                 String data  = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8")
                         + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user, "UTF-8");
                 data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8")
                         + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(pass, "UTF-8");
                 URL url = new URL(link);
                 URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                 conn.setDoOutput(true);
                 OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter
                         (conn.getOutputStream());
                 wr.write( data );
                 wr.flush();
                 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                         (new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                 String line = null;
                 // Read Server Response
                 while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                 {
                     sb.append(line);
                     break;
                 }

                 return sb.toString();
             }catch(Exception e){
                 return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
             }
         }

         protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
             //View your result here.

             System.out.println("Response from PHP " + result.toString());

             if(result.equals("No Such User Found"))
             {
                 Toast toast=Toast.makeText(Sign_In.this,"incorrect password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                 toast.show();
             }
             else
             {
                 Intent intent=new Intent(Sign_In.this,Dashboard.class);
                 intent.putExtra("child_name", result);
                 startActivity(intent);
             }
        }
     }
```

This is my PHP File:

```
<?php
require_once('DB_Connection.php');
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$query_search = "select username,password from login where username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password. "'";
$query_exec = mysqli_query($localhost,$query_search) or die(mysqli_error($localhost));
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($query_exec);

//echo $rows;
 if($rows <=0) { 
 echo "No Such User Found"; 
 }
 else  {
    echo "User Found"; 

}

mysqli_close($localhost);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code , when a user logins `mysqli_num_rows` returns `1`

try this code

```
<?php
require_once('DB_Connection.php');
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$query_search = "select username,password from login where username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password. "'";
$query_exec = mysqli_query($localhost,$query_search) or die(mysqli_error($localhost));
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($query_exec);

//echo $rows;
 if($rows >= 1) 
 { 
     echo "User Found";
 }
 else 
 {
    echo "No Such User Found"; 
 }

mysqli_close($localhost);
?>
```